# How to regex body of a heading in markdown?

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to select the body of a heading in markdown.

So far, I've come up with `### heading:\n(.*?)(?=\n###)`, but it doesn't work.

Text:

```
### heading:

here goes content
```

Demo: https://www.phpliveregex.com/p/ANy

The regex works fine in JS, so I must be missing something that is unique in PHP.

How do I make this regex work?

Comment: Try: `### heading:\R+(.+?)(?=\R+###)`

Comment: @anubhava nope..doesn't work

Comment: [It does work](https://regex101.com/r/lKsSFX/1)

Comment: @anubhava yeah, it does work if test it on regex101, but it doesn't if you actually test it with PHP's preg_match functions. That's why I linked phpliveregex.com.

Comment: It will work in your code also

Comment: What about this is “not working”? https://www.phpliveregex.com/p/ANA#tab-preg-match-all

Comment: OP, your website that you like so much has a following disclaimer: `note: preg_match is run on each line of input.`

Comment: @CBroe it only works if you add an additional ###...you've edited the original text

Comment: @user1597430 true, but it still doesn't work even if you try preg_match locally.

Comment: Why don't you use a [Markdown parser](https://commonmark.thephpleague.com/1.6/customization/abstract-syntax-tree/) instead?

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that the regex special character `.` does *not* by default match newline characters. Also, depending on what platform you are running on, each line may be terminated by `\r\n` instead of `\n`. So the regex should be:

```
/### heading:\r?\n([\s\S]*?)(?=\r?\n###)/
```

where `[\s\S]` will match any character.

```php
<?php
$text = '### heading:

here goes content

###';

preg_match('/### heading:\r?\n([\s\S]*?)(?=\r?\n###)/', $text, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Prints:

```
Array
(
    [0] => ### heading:

here goes content

    [1] =>
here goes content

)
```

You might even want to use as your regex:

```
/### heading:(?:\r?\n)+([\s\S]*?)(?=(?:\r?\n)+###)/
```

To get rid of all leading and trailing blank lines surrounding the content.

Comment: Did this answer you question satisfactorily?